# Unable to Extract Encoded PDF data in jmeter by using regular expression extractor?

Tags: jmeter

I have a web-service which return the encoded pdf but when i try to extract the data in it by using regular expression extractor(JMeter) it does not extract. I check the value of variable, it shows null value. I googled various sites but didn't succeed. After extracting the data i will save this in to one file.

I googled and refer various sites but didn't succeed. Below here are some references:
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-read-a-pdf-file-in-apache-jmeter
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter/

i got nothing in my variable when i see in debug sampler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract text from the PDF file into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) the only way of doing this is using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)

1. Download [tika-app.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) and put it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns the PDF
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def handler = new org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler();
   def metadata = new org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata();
   def inputstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(prev.getResponseData());
   def context = new org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext();
   def pdfparser = new org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser();
   pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, context);
   vars.put('pdfText', handler.toString())
   ```
5. That's it, you should have the text from the PDF file as `${pdfText}` JMeter Variable

More information:

- [PDFBox Examples](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: It is not necessarily to let me know as I'm pretty much sure that the solution works